# 9-patch Android not showing margins

Tags: android, css, eclipse, drawable

I'm trying to make a 9-Patch image to use for Android application.

Here is a screenshot from 9-Patch tool with my image:
[image]

I'm adding on layout this image:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/tiny"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:text="Text"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:background="@drawable/arrow_active" />
```

(Image is located in "drawable" folder and image name is "arrow_active.9.png" )

Here is a screenshot from eclipse:

[image]

On real device I also don't see the arrow of image.

I'm tried with ImageView and Button, layout is TableRow.

Also I tried with smaller image:
[image]

On real device I see black pixels added by 9Path tool.

Comment: it is weird that you see the black pixels, its like it doesnt detect that it is a nine patch. I'm not sure if it is mandatory, but i see that you have not any vertical strechable section (i.e there is not black pixeles in the left line). Probably you can try to add just a black pixel in the middle to see what happen

Comment: also, you can try to set the left and bottom lines to match the whole width and height, also just to see what happen and try to get a clue

Comment: Thanks for help, the problem was that I don't defined any vertical pixel. I selected while width zone and now is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this tool](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)...
It is graphically well, and auto generate images for all buckets. You can set streatch regions and content padding from it..